# How to operate decorator on derived python class?

Tags: python, python-2.7, inheritance, decorator, python-decorators

I would like to use a decorator to do something with a derived class (e.g. register the class or something). Here is my code:

```
from functools import wraps

class Basic(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Basic::init"

def myDeco(name):
    # define the decorator function that acts on the actual class definition
    def __decorator(myclass):

        # do something here with the information
        print name, myclass

        # do the wrapping of the class 
        @wraps(myclass)
        def __wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            return myclass( *args, **kwargs)

        # return the actual wrapper here
        return __wrapper

    # return the decorator to act on the class definition
    return __decorator

@myDeco("test")
class Derived(Basic):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Derived, self).__init__()
        print "Derived::init"


instance = Derived()
```

which gives the following error:

```
TypeError: must be type, not function
```

when the `super` method in `Derived` is called. I assume the variable `Derived` is no longer a `type`, but the function `__decorator` actually.

How do I need to change the decorator (and ONLY the decorator) to fix this problem?

Comment: decorator inside decorator - it asks for trouble...

Comment: @JakubM.: No, the function is a decorator factory. That is *common practice*.

Comment: `@wraps` inside `myDeco`? looks strange for me

Comment: IMO, in thise case, `__wrapper` is meaningless. For `__decorator`, you can return `myclass` directly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are replacing the decorated class with a function, and thus the class definition fails.

Specifically, the `super(Derived, self).__init__()` now passes in a *function* to `super()`:

```
>>> super(Derived, object())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: must be type, not function
>>> type(Derived)
<type 'function'>
```

Class decorators usually alter the class, add, remove or alter it's attributes, then return the class object again.

You should *not* replace `Derived` with a new class, because your `Derived.__init__()` refers to itself by name. Replacing that name with another class is going to lead to pain (such as infinite recursion).

An example class decorator that *does* work:

```
def my_deco(name):
    # define the decorator function that acts on the actual class definition
    def decorator(cls):

        # do something here with the information
        print name, cls

        setattr(class, name, 'Hello world!')

        # return the original, augmented class
        return cls

    # return the decorator to act on the class definition
    return decorator
```

Answer (score 0):

You had two errors in your program:

```
from functools import wraps

class Basic(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "Basic::init"

def myDeco(name):
    # define the decorator function that acts on the actual class definition
    def __decorator(myclass):

        # do something here with the information
        print name, myclass

        # do the wrapping of the class
        class Wrap(myclass): # error 1
            realSuper = myclass # I dislike this. has anyone an other aproach
            def __new__(*args, **kwargs):
                return myclass.__new__(*args, **kwargs)

        # return the actual wrapper here
        return Wrap

    # return the decorator to act on the class definition
    return __decorator

@myDeco("test")
class Derived(Basic):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Derived.realSuper, self).__init__() # error 2
        print "Derived::init"


instance = Derived()
```

This now gives the following output:

```
test <class '__main__.Derived'>
Basic::init
Derived::init
```

First you need a class as the others pointed out.

Second `super(Derived, self).__init__()` caused an endless recursion:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#8>", line 1, in <module>
    exec s
  File "<string>", line 32, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 28, in __init__
  File "<string>", line 28, in __init__
  File "<string>", line 28, in __init__
  File "<string>", line 28, in __init__
```

For the reasons see the discussion below.

Comment: No, `super(Derived, self)` is *correct*. Python needs the *current* class as a starting point to find the next class in the MRO. By passing in `Basic` you explicitly *skip* **that** class in the MRO.

Comment: Please explain what errors were made, why they were errors, and how they were corrected. The corrected code by itself is a poor answer.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters please tell me why it gets an endless recursion in this line if I do not change it.

Comment: Your `Wrap` will cause an infinite recursion.

Comment: @User: Because `Derived` has been replaced by another parent class, messing up the inheritance, especially since you now added a no-op `__new__` that does *not* use `super()`. Class decorators usually *augment*, not replace the original.

Comment: that makes me think that super and class decorators do not work well with each other :( I put in a work around

Comment: The infinite recursion occurs because you *replaced* `Derived` with `Wrap`, so now the parent class calls `(Original)Derived.__init__` which then asks for the `super(Wrap, self).__init__()` which happens to be `(Original)Derived.__init__`. Wrapping a class with a superclass then replacing the original **does not work**. That is what you normally would use a *metaclass* for.

Comment: What about that solution now?

Comment: @User: You don't replace a class with a superclass of itself. Use metaclasses if you need to alter class behaviour to that extend. Use class decorators to only alter the attributes, do not return a replacement class.